# How to pass data to newly created element in dart polymer?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I want to create polymer custom elements that model backpack of a character in a game. Example of a structure I want to achieve:

```dart
<eq-backpack>
    <eq-slot></eq-slot>
    <eq-slot><eq-item></eq-item></eq-slot>
    <eq-slot></eq-slot>
    <eq-slot><eq-item></eq-item></eq-slot>
</eq-backpack>
```

In `<eq-backpack>` I iterate over elements in backpack:

```dart
<template repeat="{{item in backpack}}">
     <eq-slot></eq-slot>
</template>
```

In `<eq-slot>` I check if slot is empty:

```dart
<template if="{{item != null}}">
    <eq-icon></eq-icon>
</template>
```

Now I want to pass **non-primitive** data (object containig item properties - to many to be passed as attributes) to `<eq-slot>` and then to `<eq-item>` during element creation or immediately after it. How can I do that?

I know two dirty ways: define some primitive attribute like:

```dart
<eq-slot itemId="item.itemId"></eq-slot>
```

and then try to obtain item from some global data structure but I want to avoid maintaing global variables.

I might also create `<eq-slot>` manually by `var el = new Element.tag("eq-item")` and then call some setter `el.item = item` but it is not so elegant as declarative way.

Are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use this directly on your polymer code:

In `eq-backpack`:

```dart
<eq-backpack>
  <template repeat="{{item in backpack}}">
    <eq-slot item="{{item}}"></eq-slot>
  </template> 
</eq-backpack>
```

That required to use `@published ItemType item` on your eq-slot element.

In `eq-slot`

```dart
<template if="{{item}}">
  <eq-icon name="{{item.iconName}}"></eq-icon>
</template>
```

You can directly bind data to eq-slot. Is this what you want?

You don't need to have any global data.

I wrote a blog post about data binding in polymer elements. Maybe this helps you:

http://www.roberthartung.de/nested-polymer-elements-and-data-binding-in-googles-dart/

Regards, Robert

Comment: I want to have item object, not just itemId. The main problem is that item is not primitive.

Comment: If your elements class has a @published field you can assign non-primitive values.

Comment: Yes, Günter said it totally right. I edited my post accordingly.